# Call method on WebUserControl from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I just started using ASP.NET. Here is what I tried to do:

- Create a `WebUserControl` which basically contains a `ListBox` and which offers a public `AddValue(int value)` method. This method just adds the value to the `ListBox`.
- Create a `WebForm` which contains an instance of my `WebUserControl` and which should call `AddValue` on my `WebUserControl` whenever some JavaScript event happens (in my first example this would be the `WheelEvent`.

I tried the following:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" tagprefix="asp" %>

<%@ Register src="WebUserControl1.ascx" tagname="WebUserControl1" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>test</title>

    <script>
        if (window.WheelEvent) {
            window.addEventListener('wheel', mouseWheelHandler, false);
        }
        else {
            alert("WheelEvent is not supported");
        }

        function mouseWheelHandler(eventData) {
            document.form1.WebUserControl11.AddValue(eventData.deltaY);
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <uc1:WebUserControl1 ID="WebUserControl11" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But `AddValue` on my `WebUserControl` never gets called.
I also tried to implement the `IPostBackDataHandler` interface by the `WebUserControl` and using `__doPostBack` in the JavaScript `mouseWheelHandler`, but `LoadPostData` never got called either.

What is the simplest way to get the data from the JavaScript event handler to my server control?

Comment: JavaScript's not going to have access to a server control's methods.  You could expose the method as a `[WebMethod]` which basically makes it a Web Service.  But that's a little clunky--you're better off doing it all in JavaScript.  It will be more coherent that way.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely Thanks for your comment. I will need to perform some server-side activity in my real project later - the example above is just to test the mechanism of bringing back data back to the server. I will check this `[WebMethod]` thing out. If you have some helpful information on this it would of course be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Actually, if you want to use JavaScript to communicate with the server, I highly recommend using MVC instead of WebForms.  MVCs Controllers lend themselves very well to jQuery ajax calls (using it for my current work).

Comment: Ok I had a look at ASP.NET MVC - I'm not sure if it is the right way to go in my case. My application won't contain lots of business logic. It is basically a data processing application where the data will be acceleration data of a smart phone which is periodically sent to the server. And it looks like it's not so easy to learn MVC. I think it could be worth having a look at AJAX.

Comment: If you've just started ASP.NET, you should focus on MVC.  WebForms is quickly being thrown into the "legacy" garbage bin.  MVC is a lot different at the UI level than WebForms, but once you get below that it's all the same C#.